# Upload to S3 using javascript and phone verification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have been through several of the amazon docs on this but I still can/t find a simple solution. I want to create a simple web page that allows users to upload images to my s3 bucket. Whenever I use an example I always get missing credentials as a response.

I also want to integrate a simple log on using the mobile phone with amazon's cognito. It is a single page application with no server back end. Happy to use Angular1 in the page.

I have the aws account set up but I am stuggling to find a simple example of how to do this. Does anyone have an example of how I might do this or where a tutorial that explains this very simply might be?

Comment: you can't do this with a private bucket and no backend.  Either the bucket needs to be public, or you need to include AWS credentials in your client app and figure out the signing algorithm which is well documented, but you should NEVER do this, and you if you include credentials for the bucket in a client app you might as well make it a public bucket. You can do this with a server and presigned upload URL's or by using the server as a pass trhoguh to S3

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The bucket is public, I just want to restrict access to the upload button until the user has verified their mobile number

Comment: if you're getting an upload response that credentials are missing, then your bucket is definitely not public, at least not for upload.   

You can sort of accomplish this by pretending and hiding the UI button until the number is confirmed via cognito, but you can't truly secure this without a backend.

Comment: Do not make your bucket public or hardcode credentials in your app. Use AWS Cognito  - Userpool for user login & Identity Pool for getting temporary 1-hour validity credentials. As for not wanting a server backend, that's alright. I don't think u need one for using AWS services from a mobile app. And even for web apps, you can always use S3 static website + Javascript SDK to access AWS services. So, no backend+ no hardcoded creds/insecure public bucket

Comment: I agree with @agent420 on this, you can achieve this in a serverless manner using Cognito User Pools.